# converting a form from text to textarea

Tags: php, variables, textbox, textarea, forms

I have a form created to pull PHP values into my database.

I created the form with all `type="text"` constructions. What follows is the code that used to set up the input of data and confirmed that it is functional.

```
<label>About Me: <input type="text" name="BIO_info"/></label>
```

I converted the input to a textarea and adjusted some parameters for proper display.  Unfortunately, it has broken the ability for the script to function.  What follows is the code I wrote to convert and store from a text area input.

```
  <label for="BIO_info" style="
        margin-bottom: 500px;
        margin-top: 2000px;
    ">About Me: 
    <textarea name="BIO_info" rows="20" cols="60" style="resize: none; overflow-y: hidden;vertical-align:middle;"></textarea>
  <p>
```

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: It shouldn't have made any difference - both text based fields have the same name. Is there any other JS that interacts with it prior to sending the form? If not, what does the PHP look like?

Comment: This can't be answered without seeing the PHP code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please show us some code.

Comment: can you please show your script?

Comment: In what way is it broken - what did the javascript do?

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure if i fully understand your request but i used you want to manipulate HTML tags .. Please correct if am wrong :

```
$html = '<label>About Me: <input type="text" name="BIO_info"/></label>';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($html);
$xml->addAttribute("for", "BIO_info");
$xml->addAttribute("style", "margin-bottom: 500px; margin-top: 2000px;");

unset($xml->input);
$xml->addChild("textarea");

$xml->textarea->addAttribute("name", "BIO_info");
$xml->textarea->addAttribute("rows", "20");
$xml->textarea->addAttribute("cols", "60");
$xml->textarea->addAttribute("style", "resize: none; overflow-y: hidden;vertical-align:middle;");


print($xml->asXML());
```

Output

```
<label for="BIO_info" style="margin-bottom: 500px; margin-top: 2000px;">About Me: <textarea name="BIO_info" rows="20" cols="60" style="resize: none; overflow-y: hidden;vertical-align:middle;"/></label>
```

Comment: <?php

if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
 
 $BIO_info = $_POST['BIO_info'];

 
include("connect.php");
require ("date.php");     // datestamps the entry
 
 $query = "INSERT INTO College ( Bio_info)
   VALUES ('$BIO_info'');";
 
 if (!mysqli_query($dbcon, $query)) {
  die('error inserting into database.');
  } // end of nested if statement
  
  $newrecord ="1 record added to the database.";
 
}  // end of the if statement


?>

Comment: @David Cook i can see the code writes to database ?? what are you trying to point out

Comment: If I revert back to the input type = text version of the form, it works fine.  Somehow the revision to text area is breaking the code.  FYI the VARCHAR in the DB is set to 2000, so that should not be the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately my issue remains.

Comment: I resolved the issue.  My Local Mamp Server had a MySql error due to a corrupt file.  Replacing the file solved the issue.  Thanks for the help!